# Can't connect via SSH to RPi2

Tags: pi-2, ssh, ubuntu, connection

I have searched for old topics but I can't find anything that could solve my issue.

I have installed Ubuntu MATE on SD card and created the `ssh` file on the `boot\` directory. I connect the RPi2 directly to the modem via the LAN cable. However, when I use Putty to SSH to my RPi2, it says `Network error: Connection refused`, but I can ping the RPi2.

Please note that I don't have a monitor to connect with my RPi2 so I can't access `raspi-config` and do anything as long as I can't SSH.

How to solve this problem? Or maybe I installed it wrongly, any working guide would be really appreciated.

Comment: `I have installed Ubuntu MATE on SD card and created the SSH file` Does MATE actually support headless activation? Has the file been removed after you booted the Pi with it? If not then SSH was not activated.

Comment: The file 'ssh' should be an empty or text file in the /boot partition of the sdcard (the fat32 partition) note that the name is case sensitive and should be only 'ssh' not 'ssh.txt'  - make sure when creating the file in windows that you have the view set to display file extensions!  If that is ok then after booting the Pi once and shutting down check the sdcard and see if the 'ssh' file is still present. If the enabling mechanism is working the file should be deleted automatically.

Comment: We are all speculating. Does anybody know if/how Ubuntu MATE supports headless SSH connection and use what default username and password? That's the question and best solved by looking at the documentation of the Ubuntu image.

Comment: Based on the reading of the Ubuntu MATE description, SSH as a service is not even present on the default image that you install. It's not a matter of whether SSH activation is available, but that SSH itself doesn't come installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to set your Pi up using a monitor and keyboard.
I have a Rpi3B running headless off a laptop and use VNC to communicate with the Rpi3B.
[image]